# How do I minimize object creation in this particular situation?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

While implementing a database structure, my goal is to provide easy access to player data.

So, I have created the `User` class, which holds a `Json` instance and exposes the methods to take specific information from it.

```
public class User {
    private Json data;
    public User(OfflinePlayer player) {
        File path = new File(player.getUniqueId() + ".json");
        data = new Json(path);
    }
    public boolean isPremium() {
        return data.getBoolean("premium");
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have to create a new instance every time I need to know something about the same player from different parts of my code. That's very expensive!

So, is there a design pattern for this particular situation?

Comment: By player, do you mean a `User`?

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes, the `User` class represents a player.

Comment: Why do you think this is expensive? And why don't you just keep the User reference around (in, say, a Map) for as long as you need it?

Comment: @KevinWorkman It's expensive because the `Json` constructor has to perform some IO operations. And wouldn't it be dangerous to keep such big data inside a map?

Comment: I'd go with a public static User createInstance(); method and with a simple cache of the created instances. It's not so uncommon to have informations about all active users cached somewhere. The tricky part would be keeping 'em up-to dayte with eventual async modifications on the database.

Comment: @Op: HashMaps don't have problem with size of single data entry. It is the number of entries which could cause performance degradation. Given inadequate hash function, there .could be plenty of objects in same bucket which would result with linear search in such bucket.

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple cache. If you are using ORM such as hibernate, you could use second level cache for this.

You could also have unique user identifier (UUID id) as a key, with user data as a value in Map.
So, when you get request for user data, you first see if you have user with this uuid in cache(Map) and return data if you do.

If you don't have it, then go in database and fetch data.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a `Map` like this:

```
User user = null;
Map<UUID, User> usermap = new HashMap<>;
//before creating new user instance check if its present in Map
if(usermap.containskey(id){
   //get user from Map
   user = usermap.get(id);
else{
   //not in map so create new User
   user = new User(id);
   usermap.put(id,user);  
}
//use user object
```

But please be careful to destroy usermap instance or object containing it once it is not required. You can also so several modification with limiting size etc.